# What do the highlighted values mean?

Tags: transformer, rectifier

[image: Schematic of a center tapped full-wave rectifier circuit]

What do the highlighted values mean? We're conducting a lab on full-wave rectifiers and need to calculate the estimated values for Vp(out), Vdc, ripple factor and rms ripple factor (Vr). Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is RMS voltage

Comment: AC voltages are given as the RMS value, unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlighted values describe the specifications of the transformer (voltage primary and secondaries).

This kind of rectifier is called a P2, because there are "two" phases (360°/2=180°) that are connected to 1 diode.

"[Schade charts](https://www.hifisystemcomponents.com/downloads/articles/schade.pdf)" were used for "readings" all specifications of these rectifiers (with also a capacitor // resistor).

Now simulating gives also these results (a "little" more precise).

[image]